# How to get variable name through function and use as string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I need to get a variable name outside of a function when requested inside one. For example:

```
var foo = "Hello World!";
myFunction(foo);

function myFunction(oof) {
  console.log("This says foo: '" + /*Stuff to get foo variable name*/ + "'";
}
```

Is it even possible? I can't find answers anywhere. I can use jQuery or normal js. I am using this to put positions in a piece's class. Like `e4` into a class that had `e` and `n4`(n is so it can be var name) as parameters for the function to position the piece. So I can't just use `e4` in class, because not all pieces are on that square. Please help as this is needed to progress on my project, unless someone knows another workaround(if there is, I will test and get back to you).

Comment: It's not possible. The argument doesn't even have to be a variable. The function just receives the value, nothing about where it came from.

Comment: @Barmar Is there another workaround? Anything at this point

Comment: There are some workarounds in the linked question.